# Issues importing Autodesk dae file - Segmentation Fault

Tags: gazebo-1.9, collada

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to import a model with a texture on it. I developed it with Autodesk 3Ds Max, with a .gif file as the texture. Both the dae file and the .gif are colocated in the same directory. I believe the .gif is correctly referenced in the .dae file.

Here is the definintion of the first couple of lines of the .dae file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
  <asset><contributor><author></author><authoring_tool>FBX COLLADA exporter</authoring_tool><comments></comments></contributor><created>2014-11-13T11:33:17Z</created><keywords></keywords><modified>2014-11-13T11:33:17Z</modified><revision></revision><subject></subject><title></title><unit meter="0.001000" name="centimeter"></unit><up_axis>Y_UP</up_axis></asset>
  <library_images>
    <image id="Map #19-image" name="Map #19"><init_from>./4x4_384_73.gif</init_from></image>
  </library_images>
  <library_materials>
    <material id="Material #57" name="Material #57">
      <instance_effect url="#Material #57-fx"/>
    </material>
  </library_materials>
  <library_effects>
    <effect id="Material #57-fx" name="Material #57">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <technique sid="standard">
          <phong>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0.000000  0.000000 0.000000 1.000000</color>
            </emission>
            <ambient>
              <color sid="ambient">0.588000  0.588000 0.588000 1.000000</color>
            </ambient>
            <diffuse>
              <texture texture="Map #19-image" texcoord="CHANNEL0">
                <extra>
                  <technique profile="MAYA">
                    <wrapU sid="wrapU0">TRUE</wrapU>
                    <wrapV sid="wrapV0">TRUE</wrapV>
                    <blend_mode>ADD</blend_mode>
                  </technique>
                </extra>
              </texture>
```

The file on the 5th line `<init_from>./4x4_384_73.gif</init_from>` is where I reference the file for the texture and its is used further down as a texture.

The error I'm getting from gazebo is:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1415881614.977695] [0.090000] Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned model
[ INFO] [1415881614.988141528, 0.090000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-4] process has died [pid 17741, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/arm1/.ros/log/5950b11e-6b30-11e4-be80-128cf6640207/gazebo-4.log].
log file: /home/arm1/.ros/log/5950b11e-6b30-11e4-be80-128cf6640207/gazebo-4*.log
[spawn_urdf-6] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/arm1/.ros/log/5950b11e-6b30-11e4-be80-128cf6640207/spawn_urdf-6*.log
```

Has anyone successfully spawned a model with this type of file in this way? Any help would be appreciated. It is with Gazebo 1.9 as per the Hydro install.

cheers
Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7430/issues-importing-autodesk-dae-file---segmentation-fault/) by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 203 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had been running the spawning process without graphics card support. When enabling graphics card through the "optirun" prefix (a purely Nvidia on Ubuntu solution) the mesh is displayed correctly.

---

Originally posted by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) with karma: 203 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1